# Should I absolutely avoid using useState with redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Okay I am using redux for state management in my react app. Now the question I have is, would it be all right to use useState knowing that I would only be using that state in one component only( i.e. the component that it was created in). It doesn't need to be passed, to other components(not even its children). So can I use useState in between of redux? I need to use redux btw.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use local state i.e. `useState` as much as possible. Redux state should be the last resort. Only use Redux state if you absolutely need to pass data from one end of the application all the way to another end. This is both good practice for tight coupling and good performance.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, for sure. There's no reason to use your Redux state for local state.